# Google Cloud Platform Preemptive Instances: What happens to the disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am asking about the GCP Preemptive Instances. I have read that when an instance is terminated on a preemptive instance, an ACPI Soft Power Off occurs.

I am wondering if the hypervisor pauses the instance so that I can continue on my tasks. Or, the VM is shut off and not paused.

I have used preemptive instances in the past, but I cannot seem to remember if the VM was shut down or paused.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible

Answer (score 1):

When your instance is turned off (or terminated) as stated in the documentation **you can still access your data** which are stored on a persistent disk.

[Preemption process](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemption-process) is described in the documentation and it states:

> Preempted instances still appear in your project, but you are not charged for the instance hours while it remains in a TERMINATED state. You can access and recover data from any persistent disks that are attached to the instance, but those disks still incur storage charges until you delete them. As with normal instances, persistent disks that are marked for auto-delete are deleted when you delete the preemptible instance.

You can start your instance later and access your data - and if a proper resources are not available then you can [attach the disk to other VM's](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) and still access your data.

Answer (score 0):

In short you will retain the disk data and when new vm comes up then it will automatically attach to it